# How to use featured image as background image in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, background-image

[mysite.com](http://lyricsandmusic.paulyorde.biz)
I would like to be able to allow the user of this twentytwelve child theme to be able to upload a featured image to a page (not post) and have that dynamically become the background image (positioned basically the way it is now-see thesite.com)
I think it would need a dynamic url (like wp_get_attachment_thumb_url ), though I'm not using a loop. (was thinking that function has to be used inside a loop.

I am using the code below as a template part. This is what is generating the content on the front page. So basically, I need to get this featured image and use it as a background image for a templage part, and not inside a loop.

```
<?php $page = get_page_by_title ( 'Welcome' ); ?>

    <div id="welcome-intro" class="clear">

        <?php if ( get_the_post_thumbnail ( $page->ID ) ) : ?>

            <figure class="entry-page-image">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail ( $page->ID, 'full'); ?>
            </figure>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <article id="intro-elements">

            <div class="welcome-entry-content">

                <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $page->post_content); ?>

            </div>

        </article>

    </div>
```

/* >>>>>>>>>>>>>>MODIFED<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */

```
<?php
// welcome message ?>
<?php $page = get_page_by_title ( 'Welcome' ); ?>
<?php if ( $background = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID ), 'full' ) ) : ?>

<div style="background: url('<?php echo $background[0]; ?>') top right no-repeat; height:400px;" id="welcome-intro" class="clear">

<?php endif; ?>

    <article id="intro-elements">

        <div class="welcome-entry-content">

            <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $page->post_content); ?>

        </div>

    </article>

</div>`
```

Comment: Thanks dianuj, that worked perfectly. I see how it makes sense to use get the thumbnail id as the attachment ID argument for the wp get attachment image src function. It seems useful that I would be able to use the array indexies height and width arguments of that function too (although 'full' works fine here).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it in this way by using `css`

```
$background = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID ), 'full' );

<style>
body{
background-image: url('<?php echo $background[0]; ?>');
}
</style>
```